# Lodash find for Array of objects

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have a following JsonArray:

```
arr = [
      {
        "name": "test",
        "alias": "alias1",
        "type": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "test",
        "type": 0
      },
      {
        "name": "abc",
        "alias": "alias2",
        "type": 1
      }
    ]
```

And I want to find using a variable value (which may contain alias / key). So basically the **first preference of find should be alias, and if alias with the same value is not found then it should search in "name" and where "alias" is not present**.

Normally it would have gone like:

```
_.find(arr, {
 alias: value 
})
```

But I want the code to return me the obj where name = value , if alias=value  is not found

1) Ex: value = "alias1"
Expected==>

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "alias": "alias1",
    "type": 1
  }
```

2) Ex: value = "test"
Expected==>

```
{
        "name": "test",
        "type": 0
      }
```

Comment: _"I have a following JsonArray"_ - No, you have not. That's an array of objects ([What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)).

Comment: I can't quite tell what's being asked here. For this example array `arr`, what is the correct answer? Is it `1`?

Comment: Basically I want to use the _.find in such a way that first it finds on basis of "alias". And if not found, finds for "name"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this as follow:

if the *alias* key is available in obj then match the value with *alias* else match the value with *name* key using **ternary operator**

```js
var arr = [
      {
        "name": "test",
        "alias": "alias1",
        "type": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "test",
        "type": 0
      },
      {
        "name": "abc",
        "alias": "alias2",
        "type": 1
      }
    ];

const findValue = (arr, value) => {
    return _.find(arr, (elem) => {
        return elem.alias ? elem.alias === value : elem.name === value;
    });
}

console.log(findValue(arr, 'alias1'));
console.log(findValue(arr, 'test'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use find (`_.find()` or `Array.find()`) to look for the `alias` match, and if none found use find again to look for a `name` match:

```js
const findAliasOrName = (value, arr) =>
  _.find(arr, { alias: value }) || _.find(arr, { name: value });

const arr = [{"name":"test","type":0},{"name":"test","alias":"alias1","type":1},{"name":"abc","alias":"alias2","type":1}]

console.log(findAliasOrName('alias1', arr));
console.log(findAliasOrName('test', arr));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a custom callback which takes the two possible properties for checking the value.

```js
function find(array, value) {
    return _.find(array, o => o.alias === value || o.name === value)
}

var array = [{ name: "abc", alias: "abc_alias", type: 1 }, { name: "tofind", type: 2 }, { name: "def", alias: "al1", type: 3 }];

console.log(find(array, 'abc_alias'));
console.log(find(array, 'tofind'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js">
```

Comment: I want to give preference to "alias" over "name". So basically for code[ { "name": "value", "type": 0 }, { "name": "abc", "alias": "value", "type": 1 } ]code. I want it to return code { "name": "abc", "alias": "value", "type": 1 }

Comment: the above should work like this. if you need a different preferece, change the order of the conditions.

Comment: I think the point is that the OP wants the behavior found in Ori Drori's answer: find the first one that matches `alias`, and if none do, find the first one that matches `name`.  This answer returns the first one that matches *either* `alias` or `name`.